# Are there any versions of clang that have complete implementations of std::ranges?

Tags: c++, clang, std, clang++, std-ranges

I'm just trying to figure out how I can use clang++ to compile this:

```
for (int i : std::ranges::iota_view{1, 10})
        std::cout << i << ' ';
```

The latest Apple Clang failed to recognize `iota_view`, and so I downloaded LLVM 15.0.7 using Homebrew. [This suggests](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features) that 15.0.7 is compatible with `ranges`, but I'm still having trouble with it not being recognized, even with the `-fexperimental-library`, `-std=c++20`, and `-stdlib=libc++` flags. Anyone know how to resolve this, short of just using gcc instead?

Comment: Clang 16.0.0 is the current homebrew version.

Answer (score 0):

It works with LLVM experimental C++ standard library.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    for (int i : std::ranges::iota_view(1, 10))
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

```
clang main.cc -std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++ -fexperimental-library
```

```
./a.out
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5frq61K4Y

See also [libc++ C++20 Status](https://libcxx.llvm.org/Status/Cxx20.html).

Comment: Do you know how I could resolve "library not found for -lc++experimental" when using the experimental flag?

Comment: @Oreese17 Take a look at [Using a different version of the C++ Standard](https://libcxx.llvm.org/UsingLibcxx.html#id2): On compilers that do not support the `-fexperimental-library` flag, users can define the `_LIBCPP_ENABLE_EXPERIMENTAL` macro and manually link against the appropriate static library (usually shipped as `libc++experimental.a`) to get access to experimental library features. Perhaps you should pass a full path `/usr/.../libc++experimental.a` instead of `-lc++experimental` or add a search path `-L/usr/.../` to `libc++experimental.a` when use `-lc++experimental`.